# Vertical Grid Line in datagrid disappears

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, advanceddatagrid

Apology in advance - this is sort of a long shot, but thought I'd try. I have a fairly large app that employs an AdvancedDataGrid component. When resizing a specific column (the second one to be exact), the separator between the second and third column disappears for a fairly small, but non null, range of widths of column 2. Any ideas of why that would ever happen? Unfortunately I don't have any code to show this and thus realize it'll be hard to help, but am open to suggestion as far as where to look...

thank you

Comment: Do you have some example code or a screenshot we could look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to cure the symptom, although I'm not sure why this would happen. Basically one of the columns in my ADG didn't pass this check

```
 if ((item.x +item.width) <= x)
```

on line 2609 of AdvancedDataGrid.as by a tiny amount and thus does not get drawn. I now override drawVerticalLine and add a small epsilon to x to pass the test - make no claims on the elegance of the solution, but seems to do the trick.